# Continuous thread execution

Tags: java, multithreading

Can any one help me? I want to execute a thread continuously (like infinite loop) in my project. I want to test the admin connections through the XRPC profile.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're already giving the answer to your own question in your question - 'infinite loop'.

Answer (score 1):

this will execute infinite [if no errors or exception occours]

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){public void run(while (true){/*your code*/})}).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

The preferred Java 1.6 way to do this is the following:

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            // your code here
        }
    }
});
```

(Although it's almost equivalent to org.life.java's answer)

Answer (score 0):

Using Lambda and adding stop functionality:

```
    AtomicBoolean stop = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(()->{
        while(!stop.get()){
            System.out.println("working");
        }
    });
    Thread.sleep(5);
    System.out.println("Stopping");
    stop.set(true);
```